# How to remove several items from a unsorted list in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

so i'm a bit struggling with Lists in Netlogo, so basically i've two lists and i want to remove the items that are in List 1 from List 2, for example:

List 1 : [8 6 9 7 1 3]

List 2: [5 9 8]

Resulting List : [6 7 1 3]

I've tried the following code but it returns an empty list:

```
if List 2 != []
   [ 
          foreach List 2 
          [
             let p position ? List 1 
             if p = true
                [
                  set List 1 remove-item p List 1
                ]
          ]
    ]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it. I have provided an answer below, but this is likely a duplicate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of [`member?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member) and [`filter`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter) will get you there:

```
let list1 [8 6 9 7 1 3]
let list2 [5 9 8]
let result filter [ x -> not member? x list2 ] list1
print result
```

Will print the desired:

```
[6 7 1 3]
```

Tip: whenever you find yourself trying to use an index for anything in NetLogo, you are probably not doing things in the optimal way. NetLogo has tons of functions (like `filter`, in this case) that operate on lists as a whole. There is rarely a need to explicitly loop through them.

Comment: Thank Nicolas for you answer, however there is one more constraint since i'm using Netlogo 4.0 and it seems that the provided code in not compatible with that version, i get this error : Nothing named "->" has been defined

Comment: For NetLogo < 6, use `filter [ not member? ? list2 ] list1`. But you should really upgrade if you can!