# Netlogo - remove more than one items from a list at the same time

Tags: list, netlogo

I want to simply remove [4 5 8] from list [1 4 5 6 2 8 0]. is there a direct way to do so, rather than:

```
  repeat length [4 5 8] [
    let a item i [4 5 8]
    remove a from [1 3 5 6 2 8 0] 
    set i i + 1
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove several items from a unsorted list in Netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379498/how-to-remove-several-items-from-a-unsorted-list-in-netlogo)

Comment: that solved my problem. thanks